# How do I create a Cairo-Dock launcher for Sage?

Tags: cairo-dock, sagemath

I have Sage installed via the instructions given on the page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SAGE and I tried to follow the instructions for getting a desktop icon but I couldn't understand them. Would someone please walk me through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right-click on any icon in the dock, and on the context menu choose Cairo-Dock > Add > Custom Launcher.  In the window that comes up, give the new launcher a name (presumably "Sage") and for "command to launch on click" type "sage".  Then expand "extra parameters" and tick the box for "run in terminal".